# How do I use the triangle inequality to finish this fact about complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I'm supposed to show that $|Re(z_{1})-Re(z_{2})| \leq |z_{1}-z_{2}| \leq |Re(z_{1})-Re(z_{2})|+|Im(z_{1})-Im(z_{2})|$. I've obtained the first inequality by using this fact that $|Re(z)|^2 \leq |z|^2$. I'm pretty sure I need to use the triangle inequality to obtain the second inequality but I'm just not quite seeing how.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$|z_1-z_2|=|Re(z_1)+Im(z_1)i-Re(z_2)-Im(z_2)i|=$

$=|(Re(z_1)-Re(z_2))+(Im(z_1)-Im(z_2))i)|$

Now use triangle inequality and the fact that $|i|=1$.

Comment: I see, the imaginary number was messing me up. Thanks